# still getting routines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER for https server node js

Tags: node.js, express, https

I am setting up the dev https node server, where the SSL should be disabled but should be able to serve the HTTPS request without SSL.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const api = require('./api.mock')
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
require('dotenv').config({ path: './.env' })

const handlers = api.mockApi();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World')
})

// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer({}, app).listen(443);
```

since I want to bypass SSL here,  I am not passing any cert.
but still, I am getting `outines:OPENSSL_internal:WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER` when sending https request.

what is missing here?